# ReferenceError: con is not defined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

please help me solve the issue it's very important I have included the code of my index.js, routes.js, and db.js files I have even added an image of my error.

> index.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const routes = require('./routes');
const path = require('path');

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const session = require('express-session');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');
const {
  con,
  sessionStore
} = require('./config/db');
const fs = require('fs');

require('dotenv').config({
  path: path.join(__dirname, '.env')
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));


//static files 
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/css' , express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'))
app.use('/imgs' , express.static(__dirname + 'public/imgs'))

var sess = {
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: false,
    },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  }
  
  app.use(session(sess));
  app.use(fileUpload());
//set views
app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))


app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.render('index22')
})
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
   });

   let s;

const loginRequired = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.username) {
    s = req.session;
    next();
    } else {
    res.redirect('/auth/login');
    }
}

app.get('/new', loginRequired, routes.new);//call for main index page
app.post('/new', loginRequired, routes.new);//call for signup post 
app.get('/show', loginRequired, routes.show);


app.use('/auth', auth);

//Listening on port 3000

// app.listen(3000, () => {
//     console.log("port 3000")
// })

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on http://${process.env.HOST}:${port}`));
```

> routes.js code

```
exports.new = function(req, res){
    message = '';
   if(req.method == "POST"){
      const post  = req.body;
      const username= post.username;
      const title= post.title;
      const state= post.state;
      const category= post.category;
      const description= post.description;
 
      if (!req.files)
                return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
 
        const file = req.files.uploaded_image;
        const img_name=file.name;
 
         if(file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||file.mimetype == "image/png"||file.mimetype == "image/gif" ){
                                 
              file.mv('public/imgs/uploads/'+file.name, function(err) {
                             
                  if (err)
 
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                        const sql = "INSERT INTO `nt_data`(`username`,`title`,`state`,`category`, `img_name` ,`description`) VALUES ('" + username + "','" + title + "','" + state + "','" + category + "','" + image + "','" + description + "')";
 
                            const query = con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
                                 res.redirect('show/'+result.insertUsername);
                            });
                       });
          } else {
            message = "This format is not allowed , please upload file with '.png','.gif','.jpg'";
            res.render('new.ejs',{message: message});
          }
   } else {
      res.render('new');
   }
 
};

exports.show = function(req, res){
    const message = '';
    const username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
      if(result.length <= 0)
      message = "show not found!";
      
      res.render('show.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
   });
};
```

> db.js code

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env') });

// config for your database
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    server: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT)
});

var sessionStore = new MySQLStore({}/* session store options */, con);

// connect to your database
con.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to database");
});

module.exports = { con, sessionStore };
```

> picture of the error

[image: error image]

please help me solve the issue it's very important I have included code of my index.js, routes.js and db.js files I have even added an an image of my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining `con` in your routes.js file:

```
const {
  con,
  sessionStore
} = require('./config/db');

exports.new = function(req, res){
    message = '';
   if(req.method == "POST"){
      const post  = req.body;
// Rest of the code...
```

Comment: On trying the above this error shows up:

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: in your route.js file, you have declared a constant called `message` and then again assigned a value to it in the latter part of the code. Replace the declaration of `const message` variable with `let message`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing `const { con } = require("./config/db")` (assuming it's in the same directory) in your `routes.js` file.